Neovim: A combination of Edgy Neotree and Aerial causes this automatic shrinking

When I open Neovim, Aerial is focused and when I focus on the file, the height reduces. I looked through the documentations of those three plugins but can't figure out what is going on. The issue doesn't occur when do any of the following:

I take out any of those three plugins: when Neotree and Aerial open without Edgy, and when Edgy just opens either Neotree or Aerial.
When I replace vim.cmd("Neotree buffers") with vim.cmd("copen")
When I just take out attach_mode = "global" from Aerial config (refer to config below), but I want to keep it. The setting makes it render an outline for the currently focused file.

nvim -u repro.lua "blank.md"
-- LazyNvim Setup
local lazypath = vim.fn.stdpath("data") .. "/lazy/lazy.nvim"
if not (vim.uv or vim.loop).fs_stat(lazypath) then
  vim.fn.system({
    "git",
    "clone",
    "--filter=blob:none",
    "https://github.com/folke/lazy.nvim.git",
    "--branch=stable", -- latest stable release
    lazypath,
  })
end
vim.opt.rtp:prepend(lazypath)
require("lazy").setup({
    {
      "folke/edgy.nvim",
      event = "VeryLazy",
      opts = {
        left = {
          -- Neo-tree filesystem always takes half the screen height
          {
            title = "Neo-Tree",
            ft = "neo-tree",
          },
          { ft = "qf", title = "QuickFix" },
          {
            title = "Aerial",
            ft = "aerial",
          },
        },
        bottom = {
          size = 1,
          {
            ft = "help",
            size = { height = 20 },
            -- only show help buffers
            filter = function(buf)
              return vim.bo[buf].buftype == "help"
            end,
          },
        }
      }
    },
    {
        "nvim-neo-tree/neo-tree.nvim",
        branch = "v3.x",
        lazy = false,
        dependencies = {
          "nvim-lua/plenary.nvim",
          "nvim-tree/nvim-web-devicons", -- not strictly required, but recommended
          "MunifTanjim/nui.nvim",
          -- "3rd/image.nvim", -- Optional image support in preview window: See `# Preview Mode` for more information
        },
        opts = {
          sources = { "filesystem", "buffers", "git_status", "document_symbols" },
          open_files_do_not_replace_types = { "terminal", "Trouble", "trouble", "qf", "Outline" },
          filesystem = {
            follow_current_file = { enabled = true },
            use_libuv_file_watcher = true,
          },
          window = {
            mappings = {
              ["<space>"] = "none",
              ["Y"] = {
                function(state)
                  local node = state.tree:get_node()
                  local path = node:get_id()
                  vim.fn.setreg("+", path, "c")
                end,
                desc = "Copy Path to Clipboard",
              },
              ["O"] = {
                function(state)
                  require("lazy.util").open(state.tree:get_node().path, { system = true })
                end,
                desc = "Open with System Application",
              },
            },
          },
          default_component_configs = {
            indent = {
              with_expanders = true, -- if nil and file nesting is enabled, will enable expanders
              expander_collapsed = "",
              expander_expanded = "",
              expander_highlight = "NeoTreeExpander",
            },
            git_status = {
              symbols = {
                unstaged = "",
                staged = "",
              },
            },
          },
        }
      },
      {
        'stevearc/aerial.nvim',
        opts = {},
        -- Optional dependencies
        dependencies = {
           "nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter",
           "nvim-tree/nvim-web-devicons"
        },
        config = function()
          require("aerial").setup({
            attach_mode = "global",
          })
        end,
      },
})

-- Auto-open Neotree when opening a markdown file
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("BufRead", {
    pattern = "*.md",
    callback = function()
      vim.cmd("Neotree buffers")
      vim.cmd("AerialOpen")
    end,
})


Looks like a bug or a limitation of Edgy. Maybe should you report it to the plugin author.

Obligatory: http://vimcasts.org/blog/2013/01/oil-and-vinegar-split-windows-and-project-drawer/

I want a vertical list of open buffers (like vertical tabs in a browser) but I don't want them split.

https://github.com/folke/edgy.nvim/issues/113
